# Getting 500 on DELETE route due to [Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two components working in the same way for add, update, delete,... but I'm having this key problem with the Delete only in this component. I can add and update a Classroom, but I can't delete. I keep seeing this error:

```
DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/classrooms/4 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:285
xhrAdapter @ app.js:119
dispatchRequest @ app.js:724
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:531
Axios.(anonymous function) @ app.js:541
wrap @ app.js:984
deleteClassroom @ app.js:1913
click @ app.js:37971
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:40588
invoker @ app.js:40913
original._wrapper @ app.js:46266
09:49:27.489 app.js:39359 [Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.

found in

---> <ClassroomComponent> at resources/js/components/ClassroomComponent.vue
       <Root>
warn @ app.js:39359
_createElement @ app.js:42115
createElement @ app.js:42085
vm._c @ app.js:42216
(anonymous) @ app.js:38011
renderList @ app.js:41362
render @ app.js:38010
Vue._render @ app.js:42270
updateComponent @ app.js:42786
get @ app.js:43197
run @ app.js:43272
flushSchedulerQueue @ app.js:43030
(anonymous) @ app.js:40714
flushCallbacks @ app.js:40640
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ app.js:40667
nextTick @ app.js:40724
queueWatcher @ app.js:43122
update @ app.js:43262
notify @ app.js:39470
mutator @ app.js:39622
(anonymous) @ app.js:1918
Promise.catch (async)
deleteClassroom @ app.js:1917
click @ app.js:37971
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:40588
invoker @ app.js:40913
original._wrapper @ app.js:46266
09:49:27.491
```

My ClassroomComponent.vue is:

```
<template>
...
<table class="table" v-if="classrooms">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Classroom number</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(classroom, index) in classrooms" :key="index">
                <td>{{classroom.id}}</td>
                <td>{{classroom.description}}</td>
                <td><button @click="loadUpdateClassroomModal(index)" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button></td>
                <td><button @click="deleteClassroom(index)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
...
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            classroom:{
                description: ''
            },
            classrooms: [],
            uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/classrooms/',
            errors: [],
            new_update_classroom: [],
            toastr: toastr.options = {"positionClass": "toast-top-full-width"}

        }
    },

    methods: {

        ...

        deleteClassroom(index){
            let confirmBox = confirm("Do you really want to delete this?");

            if(confirmBox == true){
                axios.delete(this.uri + this.classrooms[index].id)
                    .then(response=>{
                        this.$delete(this.classrooms, index);
                        toastr.success(response.data.message);
                    }).catch(error=>{
                        this.errors.push(error);
                });
            }
        },

        loadClassrooms(){
            axios.get(this.uri).then(response=>{
                this.classrooms = response.data.classrooms;
            });
        },

        resetClassroomData(){
            this.classroom.description = '';
        }

    },

    mounted(){
        this.loadClassrooms();
    }
}
</script>
<>
```

As I said, I have another component totally working with the same structure. I don't get it. I tried to find some answer here: [[Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420082/vue-warn-avoid-using-non-primitive-value-as-key-use-string-number-value-inst), [Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead. in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863469/avoid-using-non-primitive-value-as-key-use-string-number-value-instead-in-vuej) and etc., and nothing explain to me this.

Comment: The 500 request is coming from the back-end API that you are talking to. So it could be any number of reasons. I would suggest checking log files?

Comment: One possible reason for this happening is that your key is setting to an object instead of the index. As an alternative instead of deleting the item from the array call your loadclassrooms function on successful deletion.

Comment: Indeed @george-hanson. I just check the log and the error was: local.ERROR: Undefined variable: classroom {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: classroom at /Users/GiselleTavares/Documents/Meus_aplicativos/.../app/Http/Controllers/ClassroomController.php:107). So I realized that in my destroy method I had as param the $id instead of Classroom $classroom. It's working. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad you fixed it